# fitch proof help, don't quite understand the answer

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

[image]

I don't quite understand this one. How can Slithy (a) and Minsy (a) be together using Λ Intro? and why is it that I can use Λ Elim to pick out Mimsy (a) from Mimsy (a) Λ Gyre(a)?

Answer (score 0):

What seems wrong to you? You can get $\textrm {Slithy}(a)\land\textrm{Mimsy}(a)$ by using the rule $\land$ Intro so long as you previously have each of $\textrm {Slithy}(a)$ and $\textrm{Mimsy}(a)$, which you do (8 lines up and 1 line up, respectively). You can pick out $\textrm {Mimsy}(a)$ from $\textrm {Mimsy}(a)\land\textrm{Gyre}(a)$ (which is the previous line) with $\land $ Elim, because that's exactly what $\land$ Elim lets you do. (You could also have picked out $\textrm{Gyre}(a)$).

I’m referring to [this](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~brianwc/courses/logic/rulesummary.html). Maybe your reference to the rules is not so clear?